# Symfony console exception not logged by cron output file

Tags: php, bash, symfony, cron

I have few commands for my SF3.4 project running by crontab.

I have simple `adddate.sh` script adding datetime before each message line:

```
while read x; do
    echo -n `date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S`;
    echo -n " ";
    echo $x;
done
```

**Running cron like this:**

```
* * * * * www-data bin/console the:command >> some.log 2>&1
```

Result in `some.log` when command throws exception:

```
12:12:25 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "the:command". Message: "lol" ["error" => Exception { …},"command" => "the:command","message" => "lol"] []

  [Exception]
  lol
```

So in this case everything is ok. Exception is logged.

**Running cron like this (with `adddate.sh`):**

```
* * * * * www-data bin/console the:command | adddate.sh >> some.log 2>&1
```

Result in `some.log` with proper execution:

```
2018-01-01 12:24:01 Result of console line1
2018-01-01 12:24:01 Result of console line2
```

Nice, this is as expected! But...

Result when command throws exception: **nothing...**
Literally nothing. Not even single line. There is also no errors in system cron log. Why adding "pipe" script on command result stops logging exception messages?

Comment: Maybe try something like: { bin/console the:command | adddate.sh; } |& tee -a some.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unix pipe connects the standard output of one command to the standard input of another one.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29

The exception messages seem to be printed to standard error. Try the redirection of stderr to stdout before the piping:

```
* * * * * www-data bin/console the:command 2>&1 | adddate.sh >> some.log
```

Comment: How life becomes easier when you know how pipeline works. Thank you for your answer and for link to wiki. I should think about searching for that in first place.